# Reactjs Click to move to next item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So this is kind of a weird issue. I noticed that when I click the ToggleNext() to go to the next item in the JS array that it restarts at 0 even though 0 is already set. It should go to 1 , 2 ,3... and so forth.

How can I have the ToggleNext() check where the SongIndex is first and then properly add to it? instead of it restarting at 0?

Here is some code to try to demonstrate what is happening.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.TogglePrev       = this.TogglePrev.bind(this)
      this.ToggleNext       = this.ToggleNext.bind(this)
    this.state = {

  SongsList: [{PlayListID: "AD3249gVSDFhr46@", Uploader: "bob@none.com" , PlaylistName: "My Play List",  Genere: "Funk" ,Artist: "Random", SongName: "My Favorite Song Ever!" , Url: "http://streaming.tdiradio.com/classics", Duration: "03:22"}, {PlayListID: "yyyy249gVSDFhr46@", Uploader: "Mike@none.com" , PlaylistName: "My Play List",  Genere: "Funk" ,Artist: "Random", SongName: "My Favorite Song 2!" , Url: "http://streaming.tdiradio.com/classics", Duration: "04:55"},
        {PlayListID: "xxxx249gVSDFhr46@", Uploader: "bob@none.com" , PlaylistName: "House Music",  Genere: "Funk" ,Artist: "Random", SongName: "House Song 3" , Url: "http://streaming.tdiradio.com/house", Duration: "03:55"}   ],
        SongIndex: 0,

    }
      this.song = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)

}



ToggleNext() {
    if(this.state.SongIndex < this.state.SongsList.length -1){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        SongIndex: this.state.SongIndex + 1

    }))

  }
    if(this.state.SongIndex === this.state.SongsList.length -1){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          SongIndex: 0,

      }))
    }


    if (this.state.Play === false){
    this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);
    this.song.play()
  }
  else if (this.state.Play === true){
    this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);

  }
  console.log(this.state.SongIndex)
  console.log(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)

}

TogglePrev() {
    if(this.state.SongIndex >= 0){
     this.setState(prevState => ({
         SongIndex: this.state.SongIndex - 1
     }))
   }

    if (this.state.SongIndex === 0){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          SongIndex: this.state.SongsList.length -1
      }))

}
if (this.state.Play === false){
this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);
this.song.play()
}
else if (this.state.Play === true){
this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);

    }
console.log(this.state.SongIndex)
console.log(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)
}


TogglePlay() {
  if (this.state.Play === true){
    //this.audio.play()

    //I am not sureif this is ok to do..
    //this.song = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url).play();
    console.log(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)
    this.song.play()
    this.setState({PlayVisable : "none", PauseVisable: "inline-block", Play: false})
    console.log("Playing Music")

  }
  else if (this.state.Play === false){
  //  this.audio.pause();
    //this.audio = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url).pause();
  //this.audio = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url).pause();
  this.song.pause()
    this.setState({PlayVisable : "inline-block", PauseVisable: "none", Play: true})
    console.log("Music Stopped")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It seems the issue is you have scope related issues. I removed manual function bindings and added arrow functions and also I mutated songIndex with previous state. Can you give a try with below code

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
            SongsList: [{PlayListID: "AD3249gVSDFhr46@", Uploader: "bob@none.com" , PlaylistName: "My Play List",  Genere: "Funk" ,Artist: "Random", SongName: "My Favorite Song Ever!" , Url: "http://streaming.tdiradio.com/classics", Duration: "03:22"}, {PlayListID: "yyyy249gVSDFhr46@", Uploader: "Mike@none.com" , PlaylistName: "My Play List",  Genere: "Funk" ,Artist: "Random", SongName: "My Favorite Song 2!" , Url: "http://streaming.tdiradio.com/classics", Duration: "04:55"},
        {PlayListID: "xxxx249gVSDFhr46@", Uploader: "bob@none.com" , PlaylistName: "House Music",  Genere: "Funk" ,Artist: "Random", SongName: "House Song 3" , Url: "http://streaming.tdiradio.com/house", Duration: "03:55"}   ],
            SongIndex: 0,
        }
      this.song = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)
    }



ToggleNext = () => {
    if(this.state.SongIndex < this.state.SongsList.length -1){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            SongIndex: prevState.SongIndex + 1
        }))

  }
    if(this.state.SongIndex === this.state.SongsList.length -1){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          SongIndex: 0
      }))
    }
    if (this.state.Play === false){
    this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);
    this.song.play()
  }
  else if (this.state.Play === true){
    this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);

  }
  console.log(this.state.SongIndex)
  console.log(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)

}

TogglePrev = () => {
    if(this.state.SongIndex >= 0){
     this.setState(prevState => ({
         SongIndex: this.state.SongIndex - 1
     }))
   }

    if (this.state.SongIndex === 0){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          SongIndex: this.state.SongsList.length -1
      }))

}
if (this.state.Play === false){
this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);
this.song.play()
}
else if (this.state.Play === true){
this.song.setAttribute('src', this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url);

    }
console.log(this.state.SongIndex)
console.log(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)
}


TogglePlay = () => {
  if (this.state.Play === true){
    //this.audio.play()

    //I am not sureif this is ok to do..
    //this.song = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url).play();
    console.log(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url)
    this.song.play()
    this.setState({PlayVisable : "none", PauseVisable: "inline-block", Play: false})
    console.log("Playing Music")

  }
  else if (this.state.Play === false){
  //  this.audio.pause();
    //this.audio = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url).pause();
  //this.audio = new Audio(this.state.SongsList[this.state.SongIndex].Url).pause();
  this.song.pause()
    this.setState({PlayVisable : "inline-block", PauseVisable: "none", Play: true})
    console.log("Music Stopped")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing. I will look later when I get home maybe something else is forcing ToggleNext() to set SongIndex to 0.